# R tree doesn't use all variables(why?)

Tags: r, tree

Hi I'm working on a decision tree.

```
tree1=tree(League.binary~TME.factor+APM.factor+Wmd.factor,starcraft)
```

The tree shows a partitioning based solely on the APM.factor and the leaves aren't pure. here's a screenshot:

[image]

I tried creating a tree with a subset with 300 of the 3395 observations and it used more than one variable. What went wrong in the first case? Did it not need the extra two variables so it used only one?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the tree.control() parameters, for example setting minsize=1 so that you end up with a single observation in each leaf (overfit), e.g:

```
model = tree(y ~ X1 + X2, data = data, control = tree.control(nobs=n, minsize = 2, mindev=0))
```

Also, try the same thing with the rpart package, see what results you get, which is the "new" version of tree. You can also plot the importance of the variables. Here a syntax example:

```
install.packages("rpart")
install.packages("rpart.plot")
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

## fit tree
### alt1: class
model = rpart(y ~ X1 + X2, data=data, method = "class")
### alt2: reg
model = rpart(y ~ X1 + X2, data=data, control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 30, minsplit = 1, minbucket = 1, cp=0))

## show model
print(model)
rpart.plot(model, cex=0.5)

## importance
model$variable.importance
```

Note that since trees do binary splits, it is possible that a single variable explains most/all of the SSR (for regression). Try plotting the response for each regressor, see if there's any significant relation to anything but the variable you're getting.

---

In case you want to run the examples above, here a data simulation (put it at beginning of code):

```
n  = 12000
X1 = runif(n, -100, 100)
X2 = runif(n, -100, 100)

## 1. SQUARE DATA
# y  = ifelse( (X1< -50) | (X1>50) | (X2< -50) | (X2>50), 1, 0)

## 2. CIRCLE DATA
 y  = ifelse(sqrt(X1^2+X2^2)<=50, 0, 1)

## 3. LINEAR BOUNDARY DATA
# y  = ifelse(X2<=-X1, 0, 1)

# Create
color = ifelse(y==0,"red","green")
data = data.frame(y,X1,X2,color)

# Plot
data$color = data$color %>% as.character()
plot(data$X2 ~ data$X1, col = data$color, type='p', pch=15)
```